vim order by 2 different criteria
I have a file that looks like this:
Stroszek;12/01/1977;5.74;Drama,Comedy;7.142;0
Patients;01/03/2017;5.889;Drama,Comedy;25.000;1
Carnage;16/09/2011;9.4;Drama,Comedy;45.454;1
Detective;23/08/1985;3.865;Crime,Comedy,Drama;23.529;1
Breakfast on Pluto;03/09/2005;9.384;Comedy,Drama;21.739;1
Harriet the Spy: Blog Wars;26/03/2010;7.358;TV Movie,Comedy,Drama,Family;50.000;1

And I want to order all the movies by date but if a movie has the same exact release date as another movie it should order alphabetically based on the title in the first field.
Ive tried sorting them alphabetically first and then by date but the sorting by date just seems to override the alphabetical sort and rearrange them in an unalphabetical order.
::2,$sort! | :2,$s/\v^([^;]*;)(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/\1\4\3\2/ | :2,$sort /;\zs/ | :2,$s/\v^([^;]*;)(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})/\1\4\/\3\/\2/


Note that you can't concatenate Vim commands with the pipe symbol as you would do in e.g. Bash. Commands are separated by | and will run in sequence but you always operate on the range you specify, i.e. lines 2 to bottom.

You can try this one
#Convert dates to YYYYMMDD
:2,$s/\v^([^;]*);(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})/\4\3\2;\1/
#Sort by date
:2,$sort!
#Convert back to DD/MM/YYYY
:2,$s/\v^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2});/\2/\3/\1;/

Ive tried sorting them alphabetically first and then by date but the sorting by date just seems to override the alphabetical sort and rearrange them in an unalphabetical order. That's not quite true, as Vim sort is stable. However, simply skipping a title makes Vim to sort until the very end of line. That is, sort by dates first, then sort by ratings (or whatever), etc.

Could you modify your example so that it matches the problem. All the movies in your example have different release dates.

First, move dates before titles YYMMDDDD
:%s/\(.\{-}\);\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\);/\4\/\3\/\2;\1;/

Then sort normally
:sort

Then move dates back.
:%s/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\)\/\(\d\+\);\(.\{-}\);/\4;\3\/\2\/\1;/

